# How do I pass data to 2 or more ViewControllers during segue

Tags: swift, segue

I'm trying to pass data from a SwipeCardVC to a CardDetailVC that is the parent to multiple children view controllers embedded in different containers (i.e. ReadReviewVC).

While I can pass the data to the parent CardDetailVC with no problem, the children view controllers also need access to the data I'm passing along.

So far, I've tried casting an additional destination in my prepare for segue code as you can see below:

Update: [Storyboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46RT0.png)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetailVC" {
        let cardDetailVC = segue.destination as? CardDetailVC
        cardDetailVC?.card = CardController.shared.topCard
        let readReviewVC = segue.destination as? ReadReviewsVC
        readReviewVC?.card = CardController.shared.topCard
    }

// UPDATED CODE - CustomViewController
class CardViewController: UIViewController {
    var card: Card?
}

// UPDATED CODE - ParentViewController
class ParentCardDetailVC: CardViewController {

    private(set) lazy var childrenVCs: [CardViewController] = {
        return [
            UIStoryboard(name: "Detail", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cardDetailVC"),
            UIStoryboard(name: "Detail", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "readReviewsVC")]
    }() as! [CardViewController]

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        for child in childrenVCs {
            child.card = self.card
        }
    }
}

// UPDATE ChildVC
class CardDetailVC: CardViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    override var card: Card? {
        didSet {
            updateViews()
        }
    }
.
.
.
    // MARK: - Methods
    private func updateViews() {
        guard let card = card else { print("No card object found in \(#function)") ; return }

        cardImageView.image = card.image
        foodNameLabel.text = card.foodName
        priceLabel.text = card.price
        restaurantLabel.text = card.restaurantName
        descriptionLabel.text = card.description
        streetLabel.text = card.street
        cityStateLabel.text = card.cityState
    }
}
```

While the cardDetailVC.card value is correct, the readReviewVC.card value always comes back nil, leaving me to believe I can only have 1 destination per identifier. Please help refactor this code or let me know if there is a different way to accomplish this task (i.e: NSNotifications or KVO).

Comment: How are `ReadReviewVC` and `CardDetailVC` related?

Comment: @Sweeper the ReadReviewVC is a table view controller embedded in a container that lives on the CardDetailVC. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Then probably `CardDetailVC` should pass the data to `ReadReviewVC`, not `SwipeCardVC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only can you not segue to 2 `UIViewControllers`, your parent VC should have the data and then it should be *delegated* to the children. I say delegated lightly because this is not the same thing as `delegate` methods in Swift.

Something like this should happen.

ParentVC contains an array `childrenVCs:[CustomViewController]`. So on `viewWillAppear()` loop through the `childrenVCs` and provide them data.

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
    var card:Int!

    //...
}

class CardDetailVC: CustomViewController {
    //...
}

class ReadReviewsVC: CustomViewController {
    //...
}

class ParentVC: CustomViewController {

    //Setup Children ViewControllers inside code or inside storyboard
    var childrenViewControllers:[CustomViewController] = [//...]

    func viewWillAppear() {
        for children in childrenViewControllers {
            children.card = self.card
        }
    }
}

class SegueFromController:UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toDetailVC" {
            let cardDetailVC = segue.destination as? ParentVC
            cardDetailVC?.card = CardController.shared.topCard
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense and will give it a try

Comment: How are you setting up the children ViewControllers in ParentVC? I posted my attempted method above. Everything is working until I po the card value  on CardDetailVC and ReadReviewVC, which is showing nil, so I don't think I instantiated them on ParentVC correctly.

Comment: So it may not be the childrenVCs that are nil, because it looks like you are initializing them correctly. What I would do to make sure the workflow is appropriate is check if the prepareForSegue is called before the viewWillAppear method for the parent. If it is not, then that means we are assigning nil to all the childrenVC.card. If it is, then we have a different problem. If it is not called before, that means we need to wait for prepareForSegue to be called, so we can either put it in viewDidLoad or inside something else. Make sense?

Comment: To clarify, the childrenVCs have a value, but their inherited `var card: Card?` value is not getting set and remains nil.

Comment: When I po destinationVC?.card from the segue, I get the correct card object. When I po card in the ParentVC I also get the correct card object

Comment: This might help... The `child.card = self.card` line in viewWillAppear prints the correct child.card object. But, when I jump to the actual file (i.e. CardDetailVC) and print out the the value that should have just been set, I am finding nil instead.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that the segue hit before the viewWillAppear took place, so it's probably not the issue. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: It seems you are not referencing the same objects then. Are you using the same childrenVCs object or a new CardDetailVC object?

Comment: I assume you're correct, but then am not sure how to use the same childrenVC instances that we initialized from ParentVC (this is new programming territory for me)...  I'm attaching a screenshot of my storyboard and inspector if that helps. I haven't referred to the childrenVCs outside of ParentVC. Do I need to call something in my viewDidLoad() for the childrenVC (i.e. CardDetailVC)?

Comment: Instead of doing your private lazy var childrenVCs, you could instantiate the children on the parent’s viewDidLoad, this guarantees the creation. So, whenever you need to reference the respective child, you can do childrenVCs[0] or [1]

Comment: That makes some sense, but I still don't understand how that will allow me to access the childVC.card outside the scope of the ParentVC. Do I need to make it static or something? I have all of my CardDetailVC (childVC) code in a different file.

Comment: Adding the first part of one of my childVCs above if that helps. I've tried it without the `override var card: Card?` didSet code, but value is nil either way.

Comment: Okay - maybe i’m misunderstanding - what is wrong with what is there currently?

Comment: To recap, when the original prepareForSegue is called, it passes its card object to ParentVC correctly. From there, ParentVC initializes the childrenVCs and sets their card value equal to the card value that ParentVC received from the segue. The current problem: While I would expect the ParentVC to now pass the same `var card: Card` value to  the CardDetailVC class (since we initialized an instance in the ParentVC), the po value is nil instead. Without a value, I cannot call updateViews() and other card dependent functions in this childVC (I've updated code above for CardDetailVC). Make sense?

Comment: The only solution I can think of is instead of initializing `[CardViewController]` in ParentVC, to create a `var detailCard = Card?` in my model controller and set `card = CardController.shared.detailCard` in my ParentVC. Then the childrenVC would be able to grab the value from this shared instance. But I don't think this is very elegant.